# Generate documentation files from my private mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I have a private mediawiki installation that I use to write/maintain documentation. Now I need to provide these documentation to another developer, but I can't have him access the wiki, I have to send him the documentation in a file. Is there a way to generate all the information of the wiki, into a file? like a text file or word file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their own documentation tells you exactly how you can export to a PDF file:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Pdf_Export

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PdfBook

Or you can export the files in a way another developer can upload to their own mediawiki:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export

Or dump all the files out as HTML that you could zip up and transfer:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DumpHTML

Comment: Thanks, these look promising, I'll give it a try.